# Английское слово + русский суффикс

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы, латиница-кириллица, апостроф

Можно ли образовывать новые слова, приписывая иноязычным словам русский суффикс: ITшник, PRщик?

Answer (score 4):

Я уже отвечал на похожий ваш вопрос вчера.

> Апострофом отделяются русские окончания и суффиксы от предшествующей
> части слова, передаваемой латинскими буквами ([Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=61)).

Если есть правило, то, естественно, описываемое в нём допускается. Ответ на ваш вопрос: **можно**, соблюдая правило постановки апострофа. Либо же можно просто транслитерировать: *пиарщик, айтишник*.